Question about writing map between manifolds in coordinates
My question is about this post. I will cite the post below:

Well, I have a pretty simple (probably silly and basic) doubt about how do we describe functions on a Manifold. Well, just to make clear which definitions I'm using, for now what I know is that: a topological manifold is a metric space $M$ such that for each $p\in M$ there's a integer $n$ with $n \geq 0$ such that we can find a neighborhood of $p$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. A chart for a manifold $M$ is a pair $(x,U)$ with $U\subset M$ and $x : U \to \Bbb R^n$, if two charts overlap smoothly we say that they're $C^\infty$ related and a collection of $C^\infty$ related charts is an atlas for $M$. In that setting, a smooth manifold is a pair $(M,\mathcal{A})$ where $M$ is a topological manifold and $\mathcal{A}$ is one maximal atlas for $M$. 
So if I understood, providing a chart $(x,U)$ to a manifold $M$ is a way to introduce "coordinates" on $M$. Indeed, if $I : \Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ is the identity function we define $x^i = I^i \circ x$ to be the "$i$-th coordinate function" on $U$. In that case, for each $p \in U$ we have the coordinates $(x^1(p), \cdots, x^n(p))$ and if I understood correctly this is a way to allow us to bring to abstract spaces the usual notions of analysis over $\Bbb R^n$ (of course, in a refined manner, so that it fits the generality of the situation).
Now the real question: this all led me to a doubt - how do we describe functions on a manifold? Well, this question might seem strange, but there's a point, if we work with $\Bbb R^n$, then each $a \in \Bbb R^n$ is an $n$-tuple of reals $a = (a^1,\dots, a^n)$ and so we can describe functions $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ by combining functions defined on $\Bbb R$ applied on each $a^i$. Indeed, we have the identity $I^i(a) = a^i$, and so we can easily define for instance $f : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ by:
$$f = \sin \circ I^1 - \sqrt{(I^1)^2 - (I^2)^2}$$
Now at a point $(a,b) \in \Bbb R^2$ we would have then:
$$f(a,b)= \sin(I^1(a,b))-\sqrt{(I^1(a,b))^2-(I^2(a,b))^2}=\sin a-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
So, to define the function $f(x,y)=\sin x - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ we can simply combine functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ using the component functions of the identity function. My understanding is: we know how to build functions from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$ because we implicitly construct these combinations of functions constructed on $\Bbb R$ and the components of $I$.
Now, on an arbitrary manifold, points are not necessarily $n$-tuples of numbers. The projective plane for instance is the set of all lines through the origin of $\Bbb R^n$, so although charts provide $n$-tuples for each point, each point is not itself one $n$-tuple, so the construction of functions from one arbitrary manifold to $\Bbb R$ would not be simply like that. 
But now here comes my understanding: we simply use the coordinate functions, exactly to work as we do in $\Bbb R^n$! For instance, let's suppose that $M$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $2$ and that $(x,U)$ is a chart, in that case $x : U \to \Bbb R^2$ and we have two coordinate functions $x^1 = I^1 \circ x$ and $x^2 = I^2 \circ x$, and with this we can express any function $f : U \to \Bbb R^2$ simply by combining $x^1$ and $x^2$ with usual functions defined on $\Bbb R$! For instance:
$$f=\sin \circ x^1 - \cos \circ x^2$$
So that given $p \in U$ we would have $f(p) = \sin(x^1(p)) - \cos(x^2(p))$ which we would know how to compute.
So is all of this correct? Is really this way that we usually set up functions on arbitrary manifolds? Is this the correct way to use charts on a manifold to work with it?

So, suppose that I have $S^2$ sphere and I describe a chart by spheric coordinates $(x_1,x_2, x_3) = ( \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi), \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),  \cos(\theta))$ for $\theta \in (0,\pi), \phi \in (0,2\pi)$. It is clear that I need another chart like this to cover the entire sphere. Let's ignore that for now.
Suppose that I have the horizontal radial projection from $S^2$ to $S^1 \times [-1,1]$ defined (outside the poles) by $P : S^2 \to S^1 \times [-1,1]$
$$P(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\left(\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}},\frac{x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}},x_3\right)$$
Because $S^2$ and $S^1 \times [-1,1]$ are manifolds of dimension 2 I will want to write the function $P$ using only 2 coordinates. So, if $(U,\varphi)$ is the chart that I've described above, and $(V,\psi)$ is a chart on $S^1 \times [-1,1]$, I can describe this function, in coordinates of these charts like this: $P(\theta, \phi) = (\cos(\phi), \sin(\phi), \cos(\theta))$ and then convert the $((\cos(\phi), \sin(\phi), \cos(\theta))$ into coordinates on $S^1 \times [-1,1]$. But, my question is, if that two charts on $S^2$ are overlapping (suppose that the charts are $(U,\varphi)$ and $(W, \tau)$) then for a point $p \in S^2$ the function $P$ converted to spherical coordinates will be well-defined? The coordinates of $p$ in the $(U,\varphi)$ and $(W, \tau)$ are the same? Because if they are different, I will get two different coordinates of points in $S^1 \times [-1,1]$. So, $p \in S^2$ will be mapped to $2$ different points I think.
I don't know if I made myself understood, that's why I'm open to questions. Thanks in advance!

First, you cannot write $P(\theta,\phi)$. You need a different letter for $P\circ\varphi^{-1}$. There is a dictionary that translates between your charts $\varphi$ and $\tau$. That seem dictionary must be applied to interpret between $P\circ\varphi^{-1}$ and $P\circ\tau^{-1}$.

Which one is your actual question? Of course, the same point will have different coordinates in different coordinate systems, just like the same rod will have different numerical length if you use inches or centimeters for your computation.

@MoisheKohan I don't understand how to convert that map $P$ to a map between manifolds, because $S^2$ has dimension $2$ so it's logic to be written using only 2 parameters, not $3$. How to write it in intrinsic coordinates? Because how it is written is in ambient coordinates...

@TedShifrin so for every chart $(U, \phi)$ in $S^2$ and every chart $(V, \tau)$ I will obtain a different function $P_{U,V}$?

Yes, that's correct. I addressed only the change of chart on the domain. :)

But if for every two charts $(U1, \phi_1), (U_2, \phi_2)$ in $S_2$ I have that $\phi_1 = \phi_2$ on $U_1 \cap U_2$ and every two charts $(V_1, \tau_1), (V_2, \tau_2)$ in $S_1 \times [-1,1]$ I will have that $\tau_1 = \tau_2$ on $V_1 \cap V_2$, then I will will have only one function $P$ which don't depend of $U_1, U_2, V_1, V_2$. Is this correct?

When you write your map $P$ as a map between manifolds, you just get a map between subsets of Euclidean spaces (if your manifolds are submanifolds of some Euclidean spaces). You do not "write it using 2 parameters." The map between subsets of Euclidean spaces can be extended to maps of ambient spaces, but the extension is not unique. I think, your problem is that you have a misconception of what a map is; I suspect, you think of maps in terms of formulae, which is not always the right thing to do. This is something one usually learns when taking a real analysis class.

@MoisheKohan I think I still don't understand. I've read in a book that if I have a map between two manifolds of dimension $2$ (any number, but $2$ in this case) then the map will be something like $f(x_1, x_2) = (f_1(x_1,x_2), f_2(x_1,x_2))$. My map $P$ is defined on sphere $S^2$ which have dimension $2$, but that function $P$ has 3 parameters. So how to get a map with $2$ parameters. I didn't see anywhere a example.

So, is $P$ a map between manifolds if it's written with $3$ parameters? (Because it's written in terms of ambient coordinates, not intrinsic ones)

Then what you have read was not quite right, or you may have misremembered or misunderstood. In general, a manifold need not be even embedded in any Euclidean space. In your specific example, you have a 2-dimensional sphere embedded in $\mathbb R^3$, hence, you can describe its maps using three coordinates on $\mathbb R^3$.  But it could have been $\mathbb R^7$, or even some infinite-dimensional vector space...

@MoisheKohan thanks! I think I was confused or I misremember something.
